# json_decode on serialized form Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, serialization

I submit my form by ajax, here what I gets in controller:

```
$request->getContent()
```

return

```
string 'comment[header]=vcvdfgdfg&comment[body]=dfgfdgdf&comment[_token]=nV0QYu82KWFb-wRIlIoY4MKM6-WUfeFoMidjBHfpupA' (length=120)
```

when I try

```
json_decode($request->getContent(), true) // it equal to null
```

What I am doing wron?

Comment: It is not a json string. So you can't json decode it. try using http://jsonlint.com/ to check if your json is valid.

Comment: You can access your parameters via $this->get('request')->request (for POST) or $this->get('request')->query (for GET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a json string. If you want to parse that string and get an array you have to use the [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function, and you need to set the second parameter to have the data put in an array instead of into individual variables.

```
$get_string = "pg_id=2&parent_id=2&document&video";    
parse_str($get_string, $get_array);
print_r($get_array);
```

Or, if you're using Symfony2 you can access them this way:

```
// $_GET parameters
$request->query->get('name');

// $_POST parameters
$request->request->get('name');
```

Comment: Thanks for copypasting both comments.

Comment: You can access your parameters via $this->get('request')->request (for POST) or $this->get('request')->query (for GET) Seems like this is the exact same as your answer

Comment: That's for completeness my friend

Comment: No, thats for rep. Instead you should make your answer a http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki answer.

Comment: that's your opinion anyhow :)

Comment: Seems like 2 people downvoted you. Guess I have a solid oppinion here.

Comment: I don't understand your attitude to be honest, you're acting like a child, do as you please, I don't care about reputation but I'm not going to delete a perfectly solid answer

Comment: Those fields are an array too so you would either need to do `$commentArray = $request->[query|request]->get('comment')` for the complete array or "go deep" and use `$header = $request->[query|request]->get('comment[header]', null, true)` to get the single field value.

Comment: Why the downvote? The poster submitted the answer. If something was in a comment, it is not an answer, and the OP never gave feedback on the comment.

Comment: @contell : if you used the comments from *Stijn Bernards* and *MHakvoort* as a basis for your anwser, you should add links to these comments or cite the authors' names.